# Can I have Java modules such as I do with subdomains?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

Can I have modules such as I do with subdomains?
E.g.;
Modules:

- com.acme.transport;
- com.acme.transport.water;
- com.acme.transport.air;

I'm facing this issue with my project when I use SPI:

```java
// the core
module jakarta.nosql.communication.core {
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.annotation;
    requires static java.compiler;
    exports jakarta.nosql;

    uses jakarta.nosql.Params.ParamsProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.Settings.SettingsBuilderProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.Sort.SortProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.TypeSupplier;
    uses jakarta.nosql.Value.ValueProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.ValueReader;
    uses jakarta.nosql.ValueWriter;
    uses jakarta.nosql.TypeReferenceReader;

}

//subdomain
module jakarta.nosql.communication.query {
    requires jakarta.nosql.communication.core;
    requires java.json;

    exports jakarta.nosql.query;

    uses jakarta.nosql.query.DeleteQuery.DeleteQueryProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.query.DelQuery.DelQueryProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.query.GetQuery.GetQueryProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.query.InsertQuery.InsertQueryProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.query.PutQuery.PutQueryProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.query.SelectQuery.SelectQueryProvider;
    uses jakarta.nosql.query.UpdateQuery.UpdateQueryProvider;
}
```

inside my implementation:

```java
//implementation

module org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query {
    requires org.antlr.antlr4.runtime;
    requires jakarta.nosql.communication.core;
    requires jakarta.nosql.communication.query;
    requires java.json;

    opens org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query;
    opens org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.method;
    opens org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache;

    provides jakarta.nosql.query.DeleteQuery.DeleteQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedDeleteQueryProvider;
    provides jakarta.nosql.query.DelQuery.DelQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedDelQueryProvider;
    provides jakarta.nosql.query.GetQuery.GetQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedGetQueryProvider;
    provides jakarta.nosql.query.InsertQuery.InsertQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedInsertQueryProvider;
    provides jakarta.nosql.query.PutQuery.PutQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedPutQueryProvider;
    provides jakarta.nosql.query.SelectQuery.SelectQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedSelectQueryProvider;
    provides jakarta.nosql.query.UpdateQuery.UpdateQueryProvider with org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.cache.CachedUpdateQueryProvider;

}
```

As you can see, the module is a specialization package; for this reason, I believe the module does not seem like a different one.

When I run a test, it returns:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.provider.SelectQueryProviderTest
[ERROR] shouldGetSupplier  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.nosql.query.SelectQuery$SelectQueryProvider: module jakarta.nosql.communication.core does not declare `uses`
    at org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query@1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.eclipse.jnosql.communication.query.provider.SelectQueryProviderTest.shouldGetSupplier(SelectQueryProviderTest.java:24)
```

Refs:

- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/nosql/pull/101
- https://github.com/eclipse/jnosql/pull/271

Comment: Your module names are all allowed, that's not where the problem is. I haven't seen this error before, but it looks like the code module is trying to `use` a service from the query module. I've checked the code, and the problem seems to be in `ServiceLoaderProvider` and `LoaderType.SERVICE_LOADER`. Those are located in core, but try to load services from query. That's where the error comes from. `ServiceLoaderProvider` is too generic; in Java 8 I could even use it to load services from a completely unrelated to this module.

Comment: Hey thank you, you're right. I checked the code: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ServiceLoader.java#L500-L530

I'll refactor this code.

Comment: As a "workaround", you can call `ServiceLoaderProvider.class.getModule().addUses(SelectQueryProvider.class)` from the right module.